Distribution of Universal Quantifiers when arbitrariness is implied
I want to prove that $B \setminus \cup_{i \in I} A_i  = \cap_{i \in I} (B \setminus A_i )$ supposing that B is a set, $\{A_i | i \in I \}$ is an indexed family of sets, and $I \neq \emptyset$  . I want to do the proof like that:
$$ x \in B \setminus \cup_{i \in I} A_i \equiv$$
$$ x \in B \land \lnot x \in \cup_{i \in I}A_i \equiv $$
$$ x \in B \land \lnot \exists i \in I(x \in A_i) \equiv $$
$$ x \in B \land \forall i \in I(x \notin A_i) \equiv (*) $$
$$ \forall i \in I (x \notin A_i \land x  \in B) \equiv $$
$$ \forall i \in I (x \in B \setminus A) \equiv $$
$$ x \in \cap_{i \in I}(B \setminus A_i) $$
Is equivalence $(*)$ valid? My reasoning is that we've assumed nothing about B so it's implied that B is arbitrary.

Correct.........

(*) is a valid equivalence. The proof is simple, but sometimes simplicity can betray us.
Suppose $x\in B\ \wedge\ \forall i\in I(x\not\in A_i) $ holds. Now let $j\in I$. Then $x\not\in A_j$ and so $(x\not\in A_j\ \wedge\ x\in B)$. Generalizing on $j$, we obtain that $\forall i\in I(x\not\in A_i\ \wedge\ x\in B)$.
I leave the other direction to you.
